# Extract tables in webpages from Python/R or other software

Tags: python, r

I would like to extract Name, Address of School, Tel, Fax ,Head of School from the website:
https://www.edb.gov.hk/en/student-parents/sch-info/sch-search/schlist-by-district/school-list-cw.html
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible and there are many tool that help you do that. If you do not want to use a programming language, you can use plenty of tools (but probably have to pay for them, here is an article that might be useful: https://popupsmart.com/blog/web-scraping-tools).
However, If you want to use python, what you should do is to load the page and then parse HTML. Then you should look you desirable element and fetch its data. This article explains the whole process with code: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/web-scraping-python-tutorial-how-to-scrape-data-from-a-website/

Here is a simple code that shows the tables in the page that you posted, based on the code from above paper:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Make a request
page = requests.get(
    "https://www.edb.gov.hk/en/student-parents/sch-info/sch-search/schlist-by-district/school-list-cw.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# Create top_items as empty list
top_items = []

# Extract and store in top_items according to instructions on the left
products = soup.select('table')
for elem in products:
 print(elem)
```

You can try it out here:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13EzFWNBqpkGf4CZvGt5pYySCuW7Ij6I4?usp=sharing

Comment: Your comment is very helpful.

Comment: Happy that it helped. You can mark it as the answer to help others know that the issue has been resolved.